# How to use the new Grayscale maps

Tags: azure-maps

The [Azure maps blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/new-in-azure-maps-ip-to-country-api-map-control-modules-new-imagery-styling-features/) states `Grayscale maps: A dark-gray map style is for users who want to have a darker scale representation of a map.`

How can you enable this in the Javascript implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `style: "grayscale_dark"` when you define the map.

```
var map = new atlas.Map("map", {
  center: mapCenterPosition,
  zoom: 15,
  style: "grayscale_dark"
});
```

You can also just create a control on the map that allows you to switch between different modes:

```
map.addControl(new atlas.control.StyleControl(), { position: "top-right" });
```

Answer (score 2):

see the code sample at https://codepen.io/azuremaps/pen/WKOQRq. We will have 
documentation up soon.

```
style: "grayscale_dark"
```